# Storing Arrays as PHP Session Variables

Tags: php, arrays, session

My site has a list of users and each user is a member of different areas (groups, locations, etc). Instead of making a DB call every time I want to make a list, I want to store the array variables in session.

```
    //creates the array of groups that the user is in
    $_SESSION['gx']=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `user`='$user'");
```

Now my page loads and session_start() runs. However, when my page goes to retrieve that session variable, it's not there. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `mysql_query` does not return an array ... it returns a result resource ... you'll need to build the array from the query result ...

Answer (score 4):

The return value of `mysql_query` cannot be serialized (stored into a session). But you can pull the results out a regular array and serialize *that*:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `user`='$user'");
if ($res) {
    $_SESSION['gx'] = mysql_fetch_array($res);
}
```

**Warning**: Depending on where `$user` gets its value from, this code might be vulnerable to SQL injection. Code responsibly.

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-query.php) doesn't return an array of the results, it returns a resource which you can use for [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), etc.

You have to fetch the data first:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `user`='$user'") or die('Error!');

$_SESSION['gx'] = array();
while ( $arr = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{
  $_SESSION['gx'][] = $arr;
}
```

I believe that the usernames are unique, so you only need one call to [`mysql_fetch_*()`](http://php.net/manual/ref.mysql.php), for example:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `user`='$user'") or die('Error!');

$_SESSION['gx'] = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` returns a ressource, you need to fetch this ressource in an array like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `user`='" . mysql_escape_string($user) . "'");
$_SESSION['gx'] = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Also, you have a potential security hole. You probably want to escape $user with `mysql_escape_string()` to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: That was it - thanks a lot. "$user" comes from a variable that was escaped when it was posted from the login page, so it's clean - thanks for the warning anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` does not return an array, but a resource. Get the values out of the resource first and then store the result in your session.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a query but are returning a resource, not results.  You need to fetch an array if you want the data.

```
$_SESSION['gx']=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `user`='$user'"));
```